# Remove items in directory if filename matches words from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I've been struggling with this all day now. I'm trying to delete any files in a given directory if the filenames match a word in a CSV list.

I have imported the CSV list as text then try to match words with the filenames in the target directory, however I'm not sure which operator to use or how to go about this. Obviously 'Match' is not a cmdlet.

```
#store csv file as variable

$CSVList = Get-content -Delimiter (',') -path "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\Test folder\Watchfolder\DAZN Production Numbers - purgelist.csv"

write-host $CSVList 

#delete if word matches .csv entry

$targetdirectory =  "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\Test folder\AVMedia"
$Files = Get-childItem $targetdirectory | Match ("\w") $CSVList | remove-item -whatif
write-host $Files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `Where-Object` to the pipe where you check whether the `Name` property is `-In` the `$CSVList`:

```
# ...
$Files = Get-ChildItem $targetdirectory | Where-Object Name -In $CSVList | Remove-Item -whatif
```

**Note:** I consider the filenames within your CSV contains a file extension. If not, you want to change `Where-Object Name` to `Where-Object BaseName`.

---

**Edit.** Since you are using PowerShell Version 2, you have to use `-contains` and swap the variables:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $targetdirectory | Where-Object {$CSVList -contains $_.BaseName} | Remove-Item -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, tried this method already, however gives the following error:

Comment: `Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "BaseName" value
 of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:10 char:55
+ $Files = Get-childItem $targetdirectory | Where-Object <<<<  BaseName -In $CSVList
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma 
   nds.WhereObjectCommand`

Comment: Which PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

Comment: Okay, you should have mentioned that. I will insert [tag:PowerShell-V2] tag to your question and edit my answer to provide a solution for you. Please give it a try.

Comment: Sorry Martin, I've included my csv file to include the file extension and it does not work

Comment: If your csv includes the file extension, you have to use `$_.Name` instead of `$_.BaseName`. Also, does your CSV contains a header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131615/discussion-between-user6705306-and-martin-brandl).

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
#store csv file as variable and take first column
$CSVList = (import-csv "c:\temp\missing.csv" -Header col1).col1 


#delete if word matches .csv entry
$targetdirectory =  "C:\temp2"
$Files = Get-childItem $targetdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object {$CSVList -contains $_.BaseName } | remove-item -whatif
write-host $Files
```

Comment: unexpected token 'in'

Comment: `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` is not needed since there is a `BaseName` property. Also `-in` is not supported in PowerShell V2....

Comment: because he is in v2

Comment: i have replaced -in by -contains ty

Comment: GetFileNameWithoutExtension is obsolete since there is a BaseName property which already returns the filename without extensions

Comment: Yes, it exists in V2. Btw, you can easy switch to V2 to check your scripts using `powershell.exe -version 2`.